# Undefined Variable that is clearly defined

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can anybody tell me why the top half of my code, posted below, works perfectly fine but the last piece of code just gives me the syntax error "Undefined Variable $secQuestion"

```
$result = mysql_query("select id, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, underGradSchoolId, gradSchoolId, securityQuestionId from usertable where id=$id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$id=$row["id"];
$firstName=$row["firstName"];
$lastName=$row["lastName"];
$email=$row["emailAddress"];
$phone=$row["phoneNumber"];
$undergradid=$row["underGradSchoolId"];
$gradid=$row["gradSchoolId"];
$securityquestionid=$row["securityQuestionId"];
}

$showUnderGrad="select schoolName from schooltable
where id=$undergradid
";
$result=mysql_query($showUnderGrad,$conn) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$underGrad=$row["schoolName"];
}

$showGradSchool="select schoolName from schooltable
where id=$gradid
";
$result=mysql_query($showGradSchool,$conn) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$grad=$row["schoolName"];
}
```

But this gives me a variable undefined error:

```
$showSec="select id, securityQuestion, securityAnswer from securityquestiontable
where id=$securityquestionid
";
$result=mysql_query($showSec,$conn) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$secQuestion=$row["securityQuestion"];
$secAnswer=$row["securityAnswer"];
}
```

Comment: Show full error message and line of it.

Comment: Where do you use that variable?

Comment: It's very clear the variable is undefined , it's an error!

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: secQuestion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_4\showUser.php on line 86

Notice: Undefined variable: secAnswer in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_4\showUser.php on line 87`

Comment: They are being used like this: `print "<td>".$id."</td>";
 print "<td>".$firstName."</td>";
 print "<td>".$lastName."</td>";
 print "<td>".$email."</td>";
 print "<td>".$phone."</td>";
 print "<td>".$underGrad."</td>";
 print "<td>".$grad."</td>";
 print "<td>".$secQuestion."</td>";
 print "<td>".$secAnswer."</td>";`

Comment: Probably, you don't get any data from the database.

Comment: Side note: mysql_* functions are deprecated.  Use mysqli or pdo, and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no row returned from your query, so the while(){...} block never runs.
It needs to be run at least once to define your variables.
You can initialize them outside (and before) the while loop, like this:

```
//add the following 2 lines
$secQuestion=null;
$secAnswer=null;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$secQuestion=$row["securityQuestion"];
$secAnswer=$row["securityAnswer"];
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `while` at all?

Comment: yes, it seems the query is limiting the results to a single question by filtering the primary key